# Possibilities/advise for creating a grid-like Dashboard with graphs (highcharts)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

I am trying to create a dashboard. This dashboard should contain square-like containers (pardon my English) set up in a grid-like view. These containers hold graphs (highcharts).

Here are some very simple sketches I made that show what I want to accomplish:
[image]

And eventually I want pass a width and height as well, so that the grid can differ in size, like this:
[image]

Currently I'm thinking webparts, I was thinking something like:

```
<asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:WebPartManager>

             <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" Width="600">
                <ZoneTemplate>
                       <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </ZoneTemplate>
             </asp:WebPartZone>

        </asp:WebPartZone>
```

With the literal pointing to the created chart in code-behind.

What are my options?
Am I going down the right path?
What advise can you give?

Your thoughts are welcome :D.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the ajax control library.  The latest build offers an array of charting options (pie,bar, scatter, line, etc).  Take a look at some of their demos here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AreaChart/AreaChart.aspx